# Imagem alternativa no caso de fallha ao carregar

Tags: html

Estou a criar um script que mostra aleatoriamente um mosaico de instaram.
Eu guardo os URLs da imagem original numa BD, mas acontece que as vezes tenho URLs de imagens que não carregam porque os utilizadores eliminaram as imagens no instagram.

Qual sera a melhor forma de  mostrar uma imagem alternativa no caso da a imagem de origem não ser encontrada?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, pesquisando um pouco encontrei o parametro `onError` que executa um script quando a imagem não carega.

```
<img src="imagem.jpg" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='/imagens/semimagem.jpg';" />
```

Aqui fica também a tabela de compatibilidade com a lista dos navegadores que suportam o parametro:
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/error.html

Comment: o atributo `alt="descrição da imagem aqui"` também serve para isso e é amiga do SEO.  "[*The required alt attribute specifies an alternate text for an image, if the image cannot be displayed.*](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_alt.asp) "